# No output to terminal after inserting a module with insmod

Tags: c, linux, module, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am following the following [tutorial](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/), trying to learn how to develop device drivers, and in Chapter 2, the focus is to develop a working module and insert it into the kernel. I used the following code (hello.c):

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

static int hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, cruel world!\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

And my this is the Makefile:

```
obj-m += hello.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I then run the following in LXTerminal:

```
brian@brian-desktop:~/driver_stuff/hello$ su
root@brian-desktop:/home/brian/driver_stuff/hello# make
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-21-generic/build M=/home/brian/driver_stuff/hello modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-21-generic'
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-21-generic'
root@brian-desktop:/home/brian/driver_stuff/hello# insmod ./hello.ko
root@brian-desktop:/home/brian/driver_stuff/hello# rmmod hello
root@brian-desktop:/home/brian/driver_stuff/hello# exit
```

However, after the **insmod ./hello.ko** command, one should expect that the terminal would print **"Hello world!"** and then **"Goodbye, cruel world!"** after the **rmmod hello** command. The book mentioned that this happens when you run the commands in the console, but not in an emulated terminal, could this be the problem?

I also checked under /var/log/messages and /var/log/messages.1 which had no record of either "Hello World!" nor "Good bye, cruel world!". Is it possible that these messages are in a different file, or is the issue that the messages aren't being pushed to the kernel in the first place?

If you need an info about the kernel I am running (Lubuntu 10.04, inside a VM):

```
brian@brian-desktop:~/driver_stuff/hello$ uname -r
2.6.32-21-generic
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output from `kprintf` is always to the kernel log. This may happen to also go to the system console (and, therefore, to the terminal you're using if you're on the console), but there's nothing to link it back to the specific terminal that you loaded the module in.

To read the kernel log, run `dmesg`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! When I ran 'dmesg', the messages I wanted came up. The only issue I have is in understanding why it might go back to the terminal on the console but not to the specific terminal that I loaded the module in. What is the distinction between the two. Again, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: There's a setting in the kernel (the log level, controlled by `dmesg -n #`) which controls which log messages are echoed to the system console. This is more or less a special case; other terminals don't receive log messages under most circumstances.

Comment: I see, I guess the terminal that I was running would not receive these messages. Thank you very much for the explanation!

Comment: ok so now you cant get the printk message to your terminal?? how come?? i have seen messages printing when i insmod many other modules.....